# does c++ create an instance when declare a static member?

Tags: c++, static-members

does c++ create an instance when declare a static member?
I think this is a concept question, maybe. I am not so sure.
I mean when I declare a class with a static member inside, would there be a real space for the static member? As I knew, a static member could only exit uniquely once in a class. Is the static space and function there after I declared it? If so, does it mean I can call a function (static?) without defining a real object?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes, if you declare a `static` member, real space for it exists.  It's basically like a global variable in that sense, except for the limited scope within which it's accessible.
2. Yes, you can call a `static` function without making an instance.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can't +1 for now. Will do later.

Answer (score 0):

Actually instance of class is never created automatically.but even before creating an instance you can call that variable...static members are seperately treated common to all instances of a class.